# How to get values of a Spark Dataframe Column having children of its own?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe with the following schema -

```
root
|--country: struct (nullable = true)
|  |--state: struct (nullable = true)
|  |  |--city: string (nullable = true)
|  |--capital: string (nullable = true)
|  |--language: string (nullable = true)
|  |  |--script: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to extract values of just the `country` into a list, but when I do so, the children come along as well. Is there some way to get only the values of the `country` and not its children?

EDIT: Added printSchema() output above. If I have country = "USA" with State = "California", "NY"; capital = "Washington DC"; and so on, I want to extract the value "USA", without taking any other values.

Comment: can you share the schema as `df.printSchema` sample of data as well? what do you mean by the value of a country? the value here is itself a nested elements

Comment: Added the edit. Please have a look.

Comment: you can't have country = "somevalue" its a struct types and all nested values are its values, can you share the sample data?